# Adding custom button action with NotificationCompat.CallStyle is not working (Android)

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-14

Starting in Android 12, CallStyle is introduced for creating call-related notifications.
And I'm using NotificationCompat to support backward compatibility. Everything works fine if used the Notification library but when I used the NotificationCompat, I encountered an issue.

This is basically how I created an incoming call notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notifificationChannelId)
   .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call)
   .setContentTitle("Caller 1")
   .setContentText("Incoming Call")
   .setAutoCancel(true)
   .addAction(extraAction1)
   .setStyle(NotificationCompat.CallStyle.forIncomingCall(
      caller,
      pendingServiceIntent,
      pendingServiceIntent
   ))
   .setContentIntent(pendingActivityIntent)
   .setFullScreenIntent(pendingActivityIntent, true)
   .setOngoing(true)
   .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
   .addPerson(caller)
   .setColorized(true)
   .build()
```

In this line,

```
.addAction(extraAction1)
```

This will be the custom action. Based on Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.CallStyle#forIncomingCall(androidx.core.app.Person,android.app.PendingIntent,android.app.PendingIntent)), we should be able to add one custom action.

But it seems not working at all. The default buttons (Decline & Answer) showed up, but the custom action ```extraAction1```` I added, didn't show up.

[image]

Any ideas what I might be missing?